# Ruby on Rails - check if object is related to a set of objects (ALL or ANY)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Email` model that `has_and_belongs_to_many` `Tag`s. I would like to check if, given an array of `Tag`s, an `Email` have ALL of them, and in the other hand, if an `Email` have ANY of them. In other words, calculate the `AND` and `OR` over the membership of an `Email` to a set of `Tag`s. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a right way to write this query using `ActiveRecord` methods. Example:

```
tags1 = [
             #<Tag id: 1, name: "a">,
             #<Tag id: 2, name: "b">,
             #<Tag id: 3, name: "c">,
             #<Tag id: 4, name: "d">
        ]
tags2 = [
             #<Tag id: 1, name: "a">,
             #<Tag id: 2, name: "b">
        ]
tags3 = [
             #<Tag id: 3, name: "c">,
             #<Tag id: 4, name: "d">
        ]
tags4 = [
             #<Tag id: 1, name: "a">,
             #<Tag id: 3, name: "c">,
        ]
tags5 = [
             #<Tag id: 1, name: "b">,
             #<Tag id: 3, name: "d">,
        ]
email = #<Email id: 3, tags: [#<Tag id: 1, name: "a">, #<Tag id: 3, name: "c">]>


email.AND?(tags1) # => true
email.AND?(tags2) # => false
email.AND?(tags3) # => false
email.AND?(tags4) # => true
email.AND?(tags5) # => false

email.OR?(tags1) # => true
email.OR?(tags2) # => true
email.OR?(tags3) # => true
email.OR?(tags4) # => true
email.OR?(tags5) # => false
```

I'm looking for something like the `AND?` and `OR?` methods.

Any ideas? any help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I really didn't express myself very well. What I really need is to find all emails that meet the requirements (AND? or OR?). This is, "Get the list of `emails` that have ALL the tags in the given `tag_list`" or "Get the list of `emails` that have ANY of the tags in the given `tag_list`". notice this method should act over `Email` collection and receive `tag_list` as a parameter.

Also, I would really appreciate if you could explain how does the block syntax work.

Thanks again for your help and for your quick replies! :)

Comment: Look at how `acts_as_taggable_on` implements that - you can dive into the source code. In [Finding Tagged Object](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects), they have `User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :any => true)` and `User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :match_all => true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define methods like this on class Email

```
# AND?
def all_tags? tags
 tag_ids.sort == tags.map(&:id).sort 
end

# OR?
def any_tags? tags
  tag_ids.any?{ |tag| tags.map(&:id).include?(tag) }
end

def tag_ids
  self.tags.select("id").map(&:id)
end
```

All caps methods in ruby is not a good practice.

Comment: `self.tags.select("id").map(&:id)` is more efficiently done with `self.tags.pluck(:id)` ... and you don't need to use `self` here.  As a bonus this has been written into another method that is just `ids` so you can just do `tags.ids` instead of `self.tags.select("id").map(&:id)`

Answer (score 1):

> email.AND?(tags1)

Can be written as - `email.tags.all? { |tag| tags1.include? tag }`

> email.OR?(tags1)

Can be written as - `email.tags.any? { |tag| tags1.include? tag }`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new to ruby and of course, new to rails... can I pass `tags1` as a parameter? How would the syntax be? I don't get whats exactly happening with that code block... How does it work? Thanks for your help, and sorry for my noob questions...